# How do I change the title of a web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know this is a duplicate question, but I've tried a few approaches and I'm not able to get the solution I need.
I need to change the title of a web page, and I thought Javascript would be a good candidate. I've read many disapproving comments already, talking about how changing the title will negatively affect SEO-I'm not worried about that just now.
I'm able to change the title by reassigning a value in an inline script:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me." onclick="document.title = 'Some new title';" />
```

But using an inline script in this case is out of the question. I tried loading an embedded script tag above & below the body of the script, no go. This is what I settled on, and it didn't work initially (keep reading):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("load", function changeTitle(){
    document.title = "FUBAR";
}, true);
</script>
```

I've tried adding/removing the 'true' value at the end of the parameter list and that doesn't change anything. I avoided naming the function, then named it, and that didn't change anything. What DID work was changing "load" to "click". I need the title to change right after the document is finished loading...is there something else I can use, like "ready", or "onload"? Using "load" yielded no results, but I swear I've seen it used before.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just `document.title = "FUBAR";`? That should work as long as a) no other JS is changing it later and b) your code is included after the `<title>` tag.

Comment: I don't think `document` triggers a `load` event. `window` might work.

Comment: @Felix: Evidently document is not the right element prefix for addEventListener(). I used document because I saw it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp
but maybe document.addEventListener() only works for click events. I'll try window.addEventListener().

Answer (score 1):

Try using
`window.addEventListener` rather than `document.addEventListener`

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

> Note: More reliable is to add event listener on
>   "window.addEventListener".

Answer (score 0):

No need to wait for the `load` event. Just set the title:

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <script>document.title = "foobar"</script>
 <!-- rest of document -->
```